# Docker (compose) send to daemon mode without restart

Tags: docker, daemon, docker-compose

Quite often, when I start my docker-composed app, I like to check that everything started correctly and everything's fine.

So I do `docker-compose up`, look at the logs, and then I have to do `docker-compose stop`, and `docker-compose -d up`.

Those are too many steps and having to stop the container means downtime on my server.

Ain't there a way to *send docker to the background*?

I tried `Ctrl+Z` but then if I try to exit the ssh session, I get `There are stopped jobs.`, so that's not the correct way to do this.

I use docker-compose, but I'd be curious if this is possible with docker also.

Thanks

Comment: I guess the is no other way at the moment.

Comment: Do you reckon this would make sense? How about a feature request on github?

Comment: Why not just start it in the background first with `-d` and use `docker-compose logs` to check the logs?

Comment: Indeed but since `-d` is not a default option, I tend to forget about it in the first place and then find myself stuck...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After `Ctrl+z`, just use `bg`, the task will start running on background and you are safe to close the ssh session.